# TCP Networkstream Send and Receive

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, tcplistener, networkstream

I have developed a TCP listener to receive messages from a client machine, take that string and put it in a db, then send back a response with some data relating to that string. First attempt at a tcp network stream send and reply, just need to see if this will result in any easily avoidable "hiccups" or incorrect data being returned. If more than one message is received, sometimes I get a `Cannot access disposed object` on my network stream. Not sure how to correct these issues.

```
private void ReceivePortMessages()
{
    try
    {
        _TcpListener.Start();
        Debug.Print(" >> Server Started");
        _TcpClient = _TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        Debug.Print(" >> Accept connection from client");
        Boolean isProcessing = true;
        using (NetworkStream networkStream = _TcpClient.GetStream())
        {
            while (isProcessing)
            {
                try
                {
                    int receivingBufferSize = (int)_TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize;
                    byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[receivingBufferSize];
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, receivingBufferSize);
                    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                    sw.Start();
                    string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                    dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("\0"));
                    if (dataFromClient != string.Empty)
                    {
                        XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
                        xm.LoadXml(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", dataFromClient));
                        XmlElement root = xm.DocumentElement;
                        string rootName = root.FirstChild.Name;
                        // Data is sent to be processed and sent back.
                        RouteInboundXML(rootName, dataFromClient, sw);
                    }
                }
                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
                {
                    Debug.Print("ReceivePortMessages: Remote client disconnected. " + ex.ToString());
                    _TcpClient.Close();
                    _TcpListener.Stop();
                    ErrorLog.Write("MotionIndustriesXmlProcessing", ex.ToString(), "ReceivePortMessages()");
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.Print("ReceivePortMessages: " + ex.ToString());
                    _TcpClient.Close();
                    _TcpListener.Stop();
                    ErrorLog.Write("MotionIndustriesXmlProcessing", ex.ToString(), "ReceivePortMessages()");
                    return;
                }
            }
            Debug.Print(" >> exit");
            isProcessing = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Print("ReceivePortMessages: " + ex.ToString());
        ErrorLog.Write("MotionIndustriesXmlProcessing", ex.ToString(), "ReceivePortMessages()");
    }
    ReceivePortMessages();
}

private void RouteInboundXML(string requestType, string requestXML, Stopwatch sw)
{
    //
    // A bunch of other operations happen and then they call the SendReply() method.
    //
    SendReply();
}

private void SendReply(string reply)
{
    try
    {
        using (NetworkStream networkStream = _TcpClient.GetStream())
        {
            string serverResponse = reply;
            Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
            networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
            networkStream.Flush();
            Debug.Print(" >> " + serverResponse);
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
    {
        Debug.Print("SendReply: Remote client disconnected. " + ex.ToString());
        _TcpClient.Close();
        _TcpListener.Stop();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is your actual problem or question? Are you looking for possibilities to test your code?

Comment: @TobiasKnauss I guess my concern is, what happens if ten messages hit at the same time? How does the system know which one to reply to first? Is it queued? I guess I just don't 100% understand why it works, even though it more or less already is.

Comment: there is no "at the same time". The messages are forwarded to a input buffer by the TCP stack of the operating system in the order of receiving. The will concatenate in the input buffer, so you need to find a way how to separate them again (e.g. define a fixed message layout).  Further: what errors do you get? did you try to step over and debug? For debugging TCP communication, I suggest a small program "hercules" of the company "HW group".

Comment: Calling `Read` without keeping the value it returns is ***NEVER*** the correct thing to do. I don't know what other errors you have but that is the first major one I saw. (After 2nd look you also appear to assume you read the entire XML document in a single read, also a source of errors)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain If it's a major error, what is the suggested fix? I'm looking for how to make it better, not just what's wrong. The above code was the best I could pull out numerous online pages. Help me out here, would you?

Comment: Read through [this series of articles](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) by Stepen Cleary on TCP.